# Django Lint throwing error

Tags: django, python-3.x, pylint

I installed Python Lint for static analysis of Python code

```
pylint --version:
No config file found, using default configuration
pylint 1.4.1, 
astroid 1.3.4, common 0.63.2
Python 3.4.0 (default, Apr 11 2014, 13:05:11) 
[GCC 4.8.2]
```

I am currently working on a django project, for which I installed python-django-lint package. But when I invoke the django-lint it throws an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/django-lint", line 25, in <module>
    sys.exit(script.main())
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/DjangoLint/script.py", line 119, in main
    AstCheckers.register(linter)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/DjangoLint/AstCheckers/__init__.py", line 22, in register
    from size import SizeChecker
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/DjangoLint/AstCheckers/size.py", line 19, in <module>
    from pylint.interfaces import IASTNGChecker
ImportError: cannot import name IASTNGChecker
```

I am using Python 3.4 and Django 1.6.

Comment: But the DjangoLint is called from python2.7!

Comment: How do I call from python3.4?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Install the `python3-pip` package, remove the `python-django-lint` package and call then `sudo pip3 install pylint-django`.
To invoke it, call `pylint --load-plugins pylint_django...`